# datetime timezone converting cakephp / php

Tags: php, cakephp, datetime, cakephp-2.0, gmt

i am working on a Cakephp 2.x .. well the problem which i have has nothing to do this with cakephp .. so the scenario is i have a  page  called settings in which user sets his timezone according to his country and  in database i am storing the time in gmt format in **Userinfo** table
so in userinfo table the gmt time is

```
 5.00
```

now in my other tables i have a field called **datetime** in which i am storing the datetime in this format

```
 2013-06-14 10:28:00
```

now on my view pages i want to display the data with dateTime of particular user ...

what i want is i want to add the gmt to this datetime so i can get the final datetime according to the user country ... hope you undertstand what i want to say...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Cake's build-in [Timehelper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/time.html). Add the Helper in your controller `public $helpers = array('Time');` and then in your view:

`$this->Time->format($format = NULL, $date, $default = false, $timezone = NULL)`

In your case that'll be: `$this->Time->format('d-m-Y H:i', $data['data']['datetime'], NULL, $data['User']['timezone']);`

Good luck with that. :)

**NOTE:**
Since CakePHP 2.2 the order of `$format` and `$date` is changed. The way I explained is for CakePHP 2.2 or higher.

Comment: thankyou ... i think this is the exact solution which i was needed ,, but only one problem is coming ... the error is coming saying that  Call to a member function format() on a non-object .. i have enabled the helpers also in my controller

Comment: Did you `echo` the helper? Like so:

`<?php echo $this->Time->format($format, $date, $default = NULL, $timezone); ?>`

And what does the stacktrace reports?

Comment: I see you've found the solution... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18065086/cakephp-fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-format-on-a-non-object

Comment: yeah i have found it .. as i was using your code into controller..which was the wrong approach as helpers are developed to be used in view ..

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  $utc = gmdate("M d Y H:i:s"); // place your gmt timestamp here
  echo $utc."<br>"; 
  $offset = date('Z'); //gets offset from gmt
  echo $offset."<br>";
  $localtime = strtotime($utc) + $offset; // adjusts to localtime.
  echo date("M d Y H:i:s", $localtime);
?>
```

Comment: I've amended my answer. Give that a try.

Comment: sorry sir i didntr get your code ... my gmt value is "5.00" and date time is this "2013-06-14 10:28:00 "   how can i get the final result.. i dont need the server time or date

Comment: If you already have the GMT offset, just add it to your GMT datetime.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo (new DateTime('2012-07-16 01:00:00 UTC')) 
           -> setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('GMT+8') )
           ->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

will ouput

```
2012-07-16 09:00:00
```